# Google Developer Console: ANRs & crashes reporting bugs from my current developments

Tags: android, google-play

I have a problem with an Android App that I have on the Android Play Store. In the Google Play ANRs & crashes report, there are reports coming from tests that I have **done myself** during my developments in Android Studio.

I’m sure of that because the model of the phone corresponds to my phone and the line where the crash occurred **didn’t exist at all** in the last release.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid such problem. When doing developments in Android Studio, shall I change something to be sure that any crash that I generate during my tests will not be sent to Google Play ANRs & crashes report?
I would like reports to be sent only for signed releases.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140434/google-play-console-reporting-crashes-from-unreleased-applications

Comment: Thanks Allan, I confirm that it is the same issue so this one can be closed.

Comment: There is also this thread: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64929012